# Error handling and efficiency?

Tags: java, performance, error-handling, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageAndVariance {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("This program computes the average and variance of all numbers entered. ");

    boolean finished = false;
    double total = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    double variance = 0.0;

    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    while (!finished)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter a number (or type 'exit'): ");

        if (inputScanner.hasNextDouble())
        {   
            total++;

            double currentNum = inputScanner.nextDouble();
            average = (average) + (currentNum - average) / total;
            double prevAverage = ((average * total) - currentNum) / (total - 1);

            if (total > 1)
            {
                double var1 = (variance * (total - 1));
                double var2 = (currentNum - prevAverage) * (currentNum - average);  
                variance = (var1 + var2) / total;
            }

            System.out.println("So far the average is: " + average 
                                                    + "\nAnd the variance so far is: " + variance );        
        }
        else if (inputScanner.hasNext("exit"))
        {
            finished = true;
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            inputScanner.close();
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }
    }
}
}
```

Just wondering how to handle errors at the end, my else statement is an infinite loop? How do I make it go back to the beginning of the while loop? Also I feel like my program is very inefficient. I was having trouble with the variance but when I put the nested if statement in it worked? How could I make my code more efficient? Thanks.

**EDIT** 
Fixed the invalid input output, just had to put the scanner inside the while loop, just want to know if this code could be any more efficient than it is now? (i.e any if statements I can drop while maintaining the same functionality?)

Comment: Efficiency won't matter for this code.

Comment: You also need to remove the invalid input from the Scanner's buffer in your else clause.

Comment: To clarify what @Kayaman said, don't move the `Scanner` object inside the loop. Instead, you need to clear (aka *discard*) the bad input by calling `nextLine()`. And do *not* close the scanner inside the loop either.

Comment: I added the nextLine() into my code, but now for some reason if I get an error it will randomly print that it is an invalid input **twice** , but not all of the time?

Answer (score 0):

In above code it's good but  **inputScanner.hasNextDouble()** returns false we have entered once wrong input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AverageAndVariance {

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("This program computes the average and variance of all numbers entered. ");

    boolean finished = false;
    double total = 0.0;
    double average = 0.0;
    double variance = 0.0;

    Scanner inputScanner = new Scanner (System.in);

    while (!finished)
    {
        System.out.println("1. Enter a number ");
        System.out.println("0. Exit ");
        System.out.println("Enter Your Choice ");
        try
        {
        int option= inputScanner.nextInt();

        switch(option)
        {
        case 1:
            total++;
            System.out.println("Enter your Number");
            double currentNum = inputScanner.nextDouble();
            average = (average) + (currentNum - average) / total;
            double prevAverage = ((average * total) - currentNum) / (total - 1);

            if (total > 1)
            {
                double var1 = (variance * (total - 1));
                double var2 = (currentNum - prevAverage) * (currentNum - average);  
                variance = (var1 + var2) / total;
            }

            System.out.println("So far the average is: " + average 
                                                    + "\nAnd the variance so far is: " + variance );       
            break;
        case 0:
            finished = true;
            System.out.println("Goodbye.");
            inputScanner.close();
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Invalid Output");
            break;
        }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            System.out.println("Error "+ex.getMessage());
            finished = true;
        }

    }
}
}
```